# How to ignorre same successive records from group with SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

I have the following data:

```
ItemID | ProdID | ItemTypeID
=======+========+===========
1001   | 100    | A
1002   | 100    | B
1003   | 100    | A
1004   | 100    | B
1005   | 100    | B  <- successive itemtype (should be excluded)
1006   | 100    | C
1007   | 200    | C
1008   | 200    | A
```

and I want to list ItemTypeIDs (LISTAGG) within each group but without the same successive IDs. So my result should be like:

```
ProdID | ItemTypes
=======+==========
100    | A,B,A,B,C <- not A,B,A,B,B,C (successive B)
200    | C,A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky.  `Listagg()` doesn't even allow `distinct`, so all the work needs to be done in subqueries.

You can identify successive `ItemTypeId` using the difference of row numbers method.  Then, once the groups are identified, you can aggregate by the groups and *then* do the `listagg()`:

```
select ProdId,
       listagg(ItemId, ',') within group (order by seqnum) as items
from (select ProdId, ItemId, count(*) as NumItems,
             row_number() over (partition by ProdId order by min(ItemId)) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   (row_number() over (partition by ProdId order by ItemId) -
                    row_number() over (partition by ProdId, ItemTypeId order by ItemId)
                   ) as grp
            from t
           ) t
      group by ProdId, ItemTypeId, grp
     ) t
group by ProdId;
```

EDIT:

Another way to approach this uses `lag()` to find where the new groups start.  The previous method allows you to get the count.  This method might be easer to understand:

```
select ProdId,
       listagg(ItemId, ',') within group (order by ItemId) as items
from (select t.*
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(ItemTypeId) over (partition by ProdId order by ItemId) as prev_ItemTypeId
            from t
           ) t
      where prev_ItemTypeId is null or prev_ItemTypeId <> ItemTypeId
     ) t
group by ProdId;
```

Comment: Could you please give a little hint where did you come up with such calculations on window functions result? It doesn't seem to be a solution one does come up with in a minute. You must be experienced in this kind of thinking. I'm curious whether there is some knowledge-base regarding this approach. I've seen your answers with such creations :-)

Comment: @ConsiderMe . . . Start with the second query.  I think the logic is easier to follow.  As for the first one, it just requires listing out the intermediate results to see what happens with the difference of row numbers (there is an example in my book "Data Analysis Using SQL and Excel").

Comment: Thanks, I'll be sure to check it out. Solution with `lag()` was first that came into my mind. I didn't come up with the row_number substraction.